# BMO2 Question 1 2015 Iterative Formula Problem

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, contest-math

$1.$ The first term $x_{1}$ of a sequence is $2014$. Each subsequent term of
the sequence is defined in terms of the previous term. The iterative
formula is
$x_{n+1} =
\frac{(\sqrt2 + 1)x_{n} − 1}
{(\sqrt2 + 1) + x_{n}}$
.
Find the $2015$th term $x_{2015}$.

Since the function $f(x)$ is of the form $\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$, I considered representing it as a Mobius matrix.

$\begin{pmatrix}
 \sqrt2 + 1 & − 1 \\
 1 & \sqrt2 + 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$

This does not seem to fit elementary cases of the function though and does not look possible to iterate $2015$ times.

Can anyone help me out or come up with a complete solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solving $x=\frac{(\sqrt 2+1)x-1}{(\sqrt 2+1)+x}$ gives you $x^2=-1$, i.e. $x=\pm i$. From this, we have
$$\begin{align}\frac{x_{n+1}-i}{x_{n+1}+i}&=\frac{\frac{(\sqrt 2+1)x_n-1}{(\sqrt 2+1)+x_n}-i}{\frac{(\sqrt 2+1)x_n-1}{(\sqrt 2+1)+x_n}+i}\\&=\frac{(\sqrt 2+1)i+1}{(\sqrt 2+1)i-1}\cdot\frac{x_n-i}{x_n+i}\\&=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}i\right)\cdot\frac{x_n-i}{x_n+i}\\&=\left(\cos\frac{7}{4}\pi+i\sin\frac{7}{4}\pi\right)\cdot\frac{x_n-i}{x_n+i}\end{align}$$
So, setting $y_n=\frac{x_n-i}{x_n+i}$ gives us
$$y_{n+1}=\left(\cos\frac{7}{4}\pi+i\sin\frac{7}{4}\pi\right)y_n\Rightarrow y_n=\left(\cos\frac{7(n-1)}{4}\pi+i\sin\frac{7(n-1)}{4}\pi\right)y_1,$$
i.e.
$$\frac{x_n-i}{x_n+i}=\left(\cos\frac{7(n-1)}{4}\pi+i\sin\frac{7(n-1)}{4}\pi\right)\frac{2014-i}{2014+i}.$$
Setting $n=2015$ gives us
$$\frac{x_{2015}-i}{x_{2015}+i}=\left(\cos\frac{7(2015-1)}{4}\pi+i\sin\frac{7(2015-1)}{4}\pi\right)\frac{2014-i}{2014+i},$$
i.e.
$$x_{2015}=\color{red}{-\frac{2015}{2013}}.$$

Added : To reply to comments. $$\frac{a_{n+1}-\alpha}{a_{n+1}-\beta}=\frac{\frac{ra_n+s}{pa_n+q}-\alpha}{\frac{ra_n+s}{pa_n+q}-\beta}=\frac{ra_n+s-\alpha(pa_n+q)}{ra_n+s-\beta(pa_n+q)}=\frac{(r-\alpha p)a_n+s-\alpha q}{(r-\beta p)a_n+s-\beta q}$$$$=\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\cdot\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\cdot\frac{(r-\alpha p)a_n+s-\alpha q}{(r-\beta p)a_n+s-\beta q}=\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\cdot\frac{(\beta r-\alpha\beta p)a_n+s\beta-\alpha\beta q}{(\alpha r-\alpha\beta p)a_n+s\alpha-\alpha\beta q}$$$$=\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\cdot\frac{(\beta r+s)a_n+s\beta+\frac{qs}{p}}{(\alpha r+s)a_n+s\alpha+\frac{qs}{p}}=\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\cdot\frac{\beta(p\beta +q)a_n+s\beta+\frac{qs}{p}}{\alpha(p\alpha+q)a_n+s\alpha+\frac{qs}{p}}=\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\cdot\frac{(p\beta+q)(\beta a_n+\frac sp)}{(p\alpha+q)(\alpha a_n+\frac sp)}$$$$=\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\cdot\frac{\beta(p\beta+q)}{\alpha(p\alpha+q)}\cdot\frac{a_n+\frac{s}{p\beta}}{a_n+\frac{s}{p\alpha}}=\frac{p\beta+q}{p\alpha+q}\cdot\frac{a_n-\alpha}{a_n-\beta}$$

Comment: I'm struggling to follow a lot of this, sorry. I'm not sure why you've solved for $x$ at the beginning when it is an iterative formula. Also unsure of how you have made the factorisation you have on the third line, nor how you have reduced it on the line after. I understand that you can represent it in sine and cosine form but why not just $\frac{1}{4}\pi$. Also, why it is implied that $y_{n}$ can be represented in that way. And finally I don't get how to get to the answer from the previous step. I know this a lot to not understand, but it's my first BMO2 question I've tried.

Comment: @MadChickenMan: (1) It's worth remembering that $a_{n+1}=\frac{ra_n+s}{pa_n+q}$ leads $\frac{a_{n+1}-\alpha}{a_{n+1}-\beta}=\gamma\frac{a_n-\alpha}{a_n-\beta}$ if $\alpha\not=\beta$ are solutions of $x=\frac{rx+s}{px+q}$. (2) Multiply top and bottom by $(\sqrt 2+1)+x_n$. (3) Multiply $\frac{(\sqrt 2+1)i+1}{(\sqrt 2+1)i-1}$ by $\frac{-(\sqrt 2+1)i-1}{-(\sqrt 2+1)i-1}$. (4) Note that $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$ does not satisfy $\cos\theta+i\sin\theta=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}i$. (5) $y_{n+1}=ry_n$ leads $y_n=ry_{n-1}=r^2y_{n-2}=\cdots=r^{n-1}y_1$. (6) Note that the last $(\ )$ equals $i$.

Comment: (1) I didn't know that. Is this well know, if so could you possibly link me a page explaining it. (2) Ah, I see. (3) I'll have to take your word for that, I think the algebra will kill me. (4) Woops, my mistake. (5) I see. (6) Still not sure how you solve for $x_{2015}$ though.

Comment: @MadChickenMan: (1) Well, I think yes. I'll link if I find. (6) Multiply both sides by $(x_{2015}+i)(2014+i)$ to solve for $x_{2015}$.

Comment: Ok, I think I get everything now. Thanks for all your help and patience. That link would be great. Is it a proven theorem of sorts? Or is it just obvious to everyone else but me.

Comment: @MadChickenMan: You are welcome. I'm still searching such a link. I'm not sure if this is obvious to everyone, but we can, of course, prove it. Try to prove that $\left(\frac{a_{n+1}-\alpha}{a_{n+1}-\beta}\right)/\left(\frac{a_n-\alpha}{a_n- \beta}\right)$ is a constant ($\gamma$) using $\alpha+\beta=\frac{r-q}{p},\alpha\beta=-\frac sp$.

Comment: I can't say I would know to prove it.

Comment: @MadChickenMan: I added the proof in the answer. Take a look.

Comment: I think that's probably enough algebra for me for one day, thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

Hint
$$x_{n+1}=\dfrac{(\sqrt{2}+1)x_{n}-1}{\sqrt{2}+1+x_{n}}=\dfrac{x_{n}-(\sqrt{2}-1)}{1+(\sqrt{2}-1)x_{n}}$$
Note $$\sqrt{2}-1=\tan{\dfrac{\pi}{8}},\tan{(a-b)}=\dfrac{\tan{a}-\tan{b}}{1+\tan{a}\tan{b}}$$
Let
$x_{n}=\tan{a_{n}}$,then we have
$$\tan{a_{n+1}}=\tan{(a_{n}-\dfrac{\pi}{8})}$$
so 
$$a_{n+1}-a_{n}=-\dfrac{\pi}{8}$$
then we have
$$a_{n}=a_{1}+\dfrac{-\pi}{8}(n-1)$$
then It is easy find $x_{2015}=\tan{a_{2015}}=\tan{(a_{1}-\dfrac{\pi}{8}\cdot 2014})=-\dfrac{2015}{2013}$

Comment: I can follow this proof a little easier. I've no idea how you know the hint you provided is correct. The two look totally dissimilar, how can people possibly spot these alternate forms. I'm not sure, just as with the proof above, how you have managed to add $(n-1)$ into the mix towards the bottom. I wouldn't have known a lot of the tan values either, did you use a calculator?

Comment: The introduction of $\tan \frac {\pi}8$ was most insightful. A very elegant solution! (+1)

Comment: I see how you got to that alternate form actually, and the other person showed my how to introduce $(n-1)$, I don't know how you got the final answer without a calculator though.

Comment: Wonderful and fast solution. I like it. +1

Answer (score 0):

(Similar to Math110, but more straightforward.)

Facts:
1. $\cot ( \alpha + \beta) = \frac{1}{\tan (\alpha + \beta) } = \frac{ 1 - \tan \alpha \tan \beta } { \tan \alpha + \tan \beta } = \frac{ \cot \alpha \cot \beta - 1 } { \cot \beta + \cot \alpha}.$ We recognize that the formula is of this form.
2.  $\cot \frac{ \pi} {8} = 1 + \sqrt{2}$. We seek the value of $ \cot \beta = 1 + \sqrt{2}$.

Let $ x_n = \cot \alpha_n$. Then,

$$ x_{n+1} = \frac{ \cot \frac{ \pi} {8} \cot \alpha_n - 1} {\cot \frac{ \pi} {8} + \cot \alpha_n } = \cot ( \frac{\pi}{8} + \alpha_n).$$

Thus, $x_{2015} = \cot (\frac{ 2014 \pi}{8} + \alpha_1) = \cot ( \frac{3\pi}{4} + \alpha_1) = \frac{  (-1) (2014) -1 } { (-1) + 2014} = \frac{-2015}{2013}$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution which doesn't use any trigonometry. It isn't as elegant, but it's helpful for people who don't know much trigonometry (like me).

Substitute $\sqrt2+1$ for $k$.

We have:
$$x_{n+1}=\frac{kx_n-1}{k+x_n}$$
This means that:
$$x_{n+2}=\frac{k(\frac{kx_n-1}{k+x_n})-1}{k+(\frac{kx_n-1}{k+x_n})}=\frac{(k^2-1)x_n-2k}{k^2-1+2kx_n}$$

Substitute $k$ for $\sqrt2+1$. Notice that $(\sqrt2+1)^2-1=2(\sqrt2+1)=2+2\sqrt2$, which simplifies this a lot.

So we have:
$$x_{n+2}=\frac{(2+2\sqrt2)x_n-(2+2\sqrt2)}{(2+2\sqrt2)+(2+2\sqrt2)x_n}=\frac{x_n-1}{x_n+1}$$

This means that:
$$x_{n+4}=\frac{(\frac{x_n-1}{x_n+1})-1}{(\frac{x_n-1}{x_n+1})+1}=\frac{\frac{x_n-1-(x_n+1)}{(x_n+1)}}{\frac{x_n-1+(x_n+1)}{(x_n+1)}}=\frac{x_n-1-(x_n+1)}{x_n-1+(x_n+1)}=\frac{-2}{2x_n}=\frac{-1}{x_n}$$

So $x_{n+8}=\frac{-1}{(\frac{-1}{x_n})}=x_n$.

As 2015 is congruent to seven (mod 8), $x_{2015}=x_7$.
We know $x_1=2014$, so $x_5=\frac{-1}{2014}$, so $x_7=\frac{\frac{-1}{2014}-1}{\frac{-1}{2014}+1}$, which evaluates to $\frac{-2015}{2013}$.