# Explicit formula for recursive sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider this sequence : $a_1 = 3 , a_{n+1} = \frac{3a_n}{2a_n + 3}$ . Now find explicit formula .

My try : I found first terms and I guess the explicit formula is obvious but I'm looking for a method without finding first terms and looking for a pattern .

Answer (score 6):

We have
$$\frac{1}{a_{n+1}}=\frac{2a_n+3}{3a_n}=\frac{2a_n}{3a_n}+\frac{3}{3a_n}$$
This can be written as
$$b_{n+1}-b_n=\frac 23$$
where $b_n=1/a_n$.

Now, for $n\ge 2$, we have
$$(b_n-b_{n-1})+(b_{n-1}-b_{n-2})+\cdots +(b_2-b_1)=\frac 23(n-1)$$
So,
$$b_n=b_1+\frac 23(n-1)=\frac 13+\frac 23(n-1)=\frac{2n-1}{3}$$
This holds for $n=1$.

Hence, we have
$$a_n=\frac{1}{b_n}=\frac{3}{2n-1}$$

Comment: Thank you , I tried it previously but I don't know what is the next step .

Comment: @S.H.W: I've added some explanations.

Comment: Very nice answer . Is there a general method for finding explicit formula in $a_{n+1} = \frac{ma_n + n}{ta_n + h}$ ?

Comment: @S.H.W: Yes. Let $\alpha,\beta$ be the solutions of $x=(mx+n)/(tx+h)$. If $\alpha\not=\beta$, then there is a constant $\gamma$ such that $$\frac{a_{n+1}-\alpha}{a_{n+1}-\beta}=\gamma\frac{a_n-\alpha}{a_n-\beta}$$If $\alpha=\beta$, then there is a constant $\gamma$ such that $$\frac{1}{a_{n+1}-\alpha}=\gamma+\frac{1}{a_n-\alpha}$$

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't understand it . We have $a_{n+1} = \frac{ma_n + n}{ta_n + h}$ . Why you have changed $a_{n+1}$ and $a_n$ to $x$ ?

Comment: @S.H.W: To have a characteristic equation. I've written a proof at the end of [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1315607/78967).